# Heroku Error - undefined symbol: SHA256_init

Tags: python, heroku

I am trying to deploy a Dash app on Heroku but getting the error:

AttributeError: function/symbol 'SHA256_init' not found in library '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/Crypto/Util/../Hash/_SHA256.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so': /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/Crypto/Util/../Hash/_SHA256.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: SHA256_init

What could be the reason for this?